# How to remove number in Figure caption

Tags: captions, naming

Let's say I have a document with just one figure and I don't want that figure to be labeled 'Figure 1:' but only 'Figure:'

How can I do that?

I tried:

`\begin{figure*}`

but that didn't work! I also tried

```
\def\figurename{Figure}
```

but didn't work either

Answer (score 5):

You didn't provide more details, so I assumed you're using the `article` class. In this case, you can redefine the figure number to be empty by issuing `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}`.

**Edit:**

If it is necessary also to remove the extra spacing before the colon, one can easily modify the above command to make up for this as:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\hspace{-.333333em}}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{This is the first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{And this is the second one}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You appear to have a space before the colon.  Is this deliberate (French style) or an artefact of removing the numbering?

Comment: @ChrisH  -- Sure this is an artefact of removing the numbering, but can be easily fixed if necessary by placing a negative `\hspace` as `\hspace{-.333333em}`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Load the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which enables you to use `\caption*`. Then you can insert a prefix `Figure:` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption*{Figure: This is the first figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```