# How can I represent a math formula as a figure?

Tags: equations, captions

I want to represent a math formula as an figure instead of an equation.

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \underbrace{x\ .\ y}_\text{$S_{v}$}.
    \underbrace{z}_\text{(e)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

wanted output:

[image]

Comment: Put `$\underbrace{x\cdot y}_{S_{v}} \cdot \underbrace{z}_\text{(e)}$` inside a `figure` environment with a `centering` and a `\caption{}` .

Comment: If your next question is "How do I get my equation figure to go where I want it", then see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497

Comment: You can get rid of the figure number with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339136/5283  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the name, the `figure` environment can contain *anything*.

For instance an equation, a picture, some text, whatever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\[
    \underbrace{x\cdot y}_{S_{v}\mathstrut}\cdot
    \underbrace{z\vphantom{y}}_{(\mathrm{e)}}
\]
\caption{My interesting equation}\label{mie}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note the typesetting: multiplication is never a period; using `\text{$...$}` is very redundant.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{figformula}[Figure][]
\begin{document}
\begin{figformula}[h]
  \begin{equation*}
   \underbrace{x\ .\ y}_\text{$S_{v}$}.
    \underbrace{z}_\text{(e)}
  \end{equation*}
\caption{My math formula.}
\end{figformula}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we remove the `(1)` at the right hand side?

Comment: @alper Sorry I have not seen this.

Comment: Its caption number always starts from 1 even there is another figures beforehand is it normal?

Comment: @alper I think yes.

Comment: That can be modified, with \setcounter{equation}{#} just before equation's environment. Example if #=2 the number equation will be #original+2

Comment: @alper Sebastiano has declared a new float sequence so `figformula` is a third float type with its own counter just like table and figure have separate numbers. If you want equations in the same sequence as figures just use `figure`

Answer (score 1):

Using figure's environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{equation}
    \underbrace{x\ .\ y}_\text{$S_{v}$}.
    \underbrace{z}_\text{(e)}\nonumber
\end{equation}
\caption{Like show in the figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```